# Passing Datetime in Rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, escaping

I am attempting to pass a datetime to my controller so as to initiate an update. At present I have built out the controller action as:

```
    def editEvent
        editEvent = "UPDATE androidchatterdatabase.events SET campaign_id = " + params[:campaign_id].to_s + ", location_id = " + params[:location_id].to_s + 
                    ", time_of_event = " + params[:time_of_event].to_s + ", status = " + params[:status].to_s + ", removed = " + params[:removed].to_s + ", updated_at = NOW()
                    WHERE id = " + params[:event_id].to_s

        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(editEvent)
    end
```

and the route as:

```
match '/editEvent/:event_id/:campaign_id/:location_id/:status/:removed/:time_of_event', to: 'requests#editEvent', via: 'get'
```

But when attempting to pass the datetime, ie. month, day, year, hour second, to the URL, as:

```
http://localhost:3000/editEvent/1/350/250/0/1/2015-01-27T16:17:57+00:00
```

The error occurs as:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':17:57+00:00, status = 0, removed = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 1' at line 1: UPDATE androidchatterdatabase.events SET campaign_id = 350, location_id = 250, time_of_event = 2015-01-27T16:17:57+00:00, status = 0, removed = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 1
```

How can I escape this to allow for sending a date into the URL to update?

Comment: Why are you writing raw SQL rather than using an ActiveRecord model for this? Your current implementation is vulnerable to injection attacks since you're not properly escaping your parameters.

Comment: First of all, you should use placeholder for preventing from **SQL injection**. And, maybe MySQL doesn't recieve timezone(**+00:00**). You should use `Time.parse(params[:time_of_event]).to_s(:db)`.